# For Loop Table in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to generate a table with php for loop, that lists numbers. Something like this:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 1
3 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 2
4 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 3
5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

I still have problems getting it, this is actually quite simple, but I have not been able to solve it. So far I have the following code:

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1'><br />";

for ($row = 0; $row < 5; $row ++) {
   echo "<tr>";

   for ($col = 1; $col <= 4; $col ++) {
        echo "<td>", ($col + ($row * 4)), "</td>";
   }

   echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

However, this only generates the following:

```
1  | 2  | 3  | 4 
5  | 6  | 7  | 8
9  | 10 | 11 | 12
13 | 14 | 15 | 16
17 | 18 | 19 | 20
```

Thank you, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This should give you an idea `$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
array_unshift($a, array_pop($a));`

Comment: This is called "queue" in data structures. Read this http://www.phpmoot.com/other-sorting-options/

Comment: Not a queue... smells like modular arithmetic to me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1'><br />";

for ($row = 0; $row < 5; $row ++) {
   echo "<tr>";

   for ($col = 0; $col < 5; $col ++) {
        echo "<td>", (($col + $row) % 5) + 1, "</td>";
   }

   echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
echo "<table border='1'><br />";
for ( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ( $j = 0; $j < 5; $j++ ) {
        echo "<td>", ($j+$i)%5+1, "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 3):

My version :

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1'><br />";
$i=1;
for ($row = 0; $row < 5; $row ++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  $cont = 0;
for ($col = $i; $col <= 5; $col ++) 
    {
     echo "<td>", ($col), "</td>";
     $cont++;
    }
if($cont < 5)
{
 for($col = 1; $col <= 5 - $cont; $col++)
 {
  echo "<td>", ($col), "</td>";
 }
 }

echo "</tr>";
$i++;
}

echo "</table>";
```

Codepad: http://codepad.viper-7.com/JZogNY

Answer (score 2):

My Version

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1'><br />";

for ($row = 0; $row < 5; $row ++) {
   $k=$row;

   for ($col = 0; $col < 5; $col ++) {
        echo "<td>", (($k++)%5)+1, "</td>";
   }

   echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    echo '<table border="1">';
    $i = 0;
    for($i =1; $i<=5; $i++){
        echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$i.'</td>';
            $x = 0;
            for($x=1; $x<=4; $x++){
                $y = $x + $i;
                $z = ($y>5) ? $y-5 : $y;
                echo '<td>'.$z.'</td>';
            }
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: consider adding the explanation rather than adding the code.