# Dynamic drop down menus using CSS and PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I want to create a dynamic drop down menu using PHP and MySQL. Menus is OK  but not the way I wanted.

I want the menu like this as below (sorted vertically and limiting number of items vertically and horizontally)

[image]

I tried achieving this as per below code:

```
<?php foreach ($result as $riw) { ?>
<div class="four columns">
<li><a href="<?php echo $riw['fmprmlink']; ?>"><?php echo 
     $riw['remedy_name']; ?></a> </li>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

By above approach i am getting this as a result which is not rquired

[image]

and without using `<div class="four columns">` the result is as below which is again not required

[image]

I want items to be arranged and shown alphabetically vertically.

Comment: In your query you can add order_by and check.

Comment: but that will not arrange the items anyway.. pl look at my requirement

Comment: you can add condition and  based on that you can create other column and placed your data.like in first column after 10 row it will create other column and so on...Hope i am not wrong.!!

Comment: idea i m aware of. but how to acheive that m nt sure...

Comment: What is "not required" about the two results you have? Can you explain, in your question, what you do require?

Comment: Not required means the alignment is not accepted. Only alignment wanted is as 1st image

Comment: Hmm, well the last screenshot looks very similar to the first image. What CSS are you using for the `<li>` item? - please add that and any other relevant CSS to your question. Since you want to sort downwards you'll need to separate into divs - if you were to sort across you could just float left your list items in one div.

Comment: Yes it is similar. I just want to limit the number of rows to 5 and columns to 4

Comment: Css used is only li is given as width 25%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple possibility of sorting first, then second, then etc. column.
Can something be improved.
Shows one of many possibilities.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>4 columns</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
function setline($conte,$i,$count,$ILines){
  $act1 = $i; 
  $act2 = 1*$ILines + $i; 
  $act3 = 2*$ILines + $i;
  $act4 = 3*$ILines + $i; 
  echo "<li>".$conte[$act1]."</li>\n"; // 0
  if ($act2 < $count){ echo "<li>".$conte[$act2]."</li>\n";}
  if ($act3 < $count){ echo "<li>".$conte[$act3]."</li>\n";}
  if ($act4 < $count){ echo "<li>".$conte[$act4]."</li>\n";}
}
//-----------main---------------
echo "<ul id=\"quad\">";
$anArry = array("CSS","XHTML","Semantics","Accessibility","Usability","Web Standards","PHP","Typography","Grids","CSS3","HTML5");
sort($anArry);
$count = count($anArry);
$Idiv = (int)($count/4);
if ($count - ($Idiv * 4)>0) {$ILines = $Idiv+1;} else {$ILines = $Idiv;}

for ($i = 0; $i < $ILines; $i++) {
      setline($anArry,$i,$count,$ILines);
}
echo "<ul/>";
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Next is the **normal standard** look of a `4 column list`.
To get it we changed only the `for loop`.
Sorted from left to right ( **not** what OP wants)

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
      echo "<li>".$anArry[$i]."</li>\n";
    }
```

[image]

---

Now that we know the matrix ...

```
  1| 0-2 3-5 6-8 9-11
col| 1   2   3   4
---|---------------
r 1| 0   3   6   9
o 2| 1   4   7   10
w 3| 2   5   8   11
```

... we can write a simpler function.

```
function sortfor4c($cont,$i,$ILines,&$ICol,&$IRow){
  echo "<li>".$cont[$ICol * $ILines - $ILines + $IRow -1]."</li>\n";
  $ICol++;
  if ($ICol > 4) {
       $ICol = 1;
       $IRow++;
  }      
 }
....
$ICol = 1;
$IRow = 1;

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    sortfor4c($anArry,$i,$ILines,$ICol,$IRow);
}
```

style.css

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{ 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ol,ul{
    list-style:none;
}

body{
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color:#333;
}

ul{
    width:760px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
}
li{
    line-height:1.5em;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}

#quad li        { width:25%; }
```

Comment: implemented ur code here http://ayurvedamantram.com/index1 but it simply doesnt work

Comment: @Gags : Have you tried the 32 lines code above. It's simple and running.

Comment: @Gags : Copy from first to last line and save to a file like `show.php` .  Run `show.php` in a browser . It's running out of the box. With 'style.css' in the same folder .

Comment: I will try nd let u knw moskito-x

Comment: @Gags : also I can see in your code : `<ul> <li><a href='#'>Acidity</a></li>` **<ul>** has no **id** like : `<ul id="quad"> <li>Acidity</li>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76087/discussion-between-gags-and-moskito-x).

Comment: @Gags : Thanks for pointing out **&** . I have removed in my code :-)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you would want to use some sort of for loop to order the data appropriately. You could do this with PHP or you could do it with JavaScript.

Either way, you will need to process the entries returned by the server so as to limit the number of rows added to each column. The way you'll process the data depends on how it is returned by the server. If the server sends JSON data representing the data cells in question (and you're using AJAX), you'll likely need to take a javascript approach. If you plan to load all menu field data upon the initial page load, you can probably use PHP to create the menu entries.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787432/for-loop-table-in-php) is an example of using a for loop to create a table using PHP. You should be able to do the same thing with either list items and/or divs. If this answer is confusing, there are numerous other examples on both SO and the internet at large.

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1'><br />";

for ($row = 0; $row < 5; $row ++) {
   echo "<tr>";

   for ($col = 1; $col <= 4; $col ++) {
        echo "<td>", [YOUR MENU ENTRY GOES HERE], "</td>";
   }

   echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: An appropriate example is wholly dependent on the data returned by your database. The example I just added is for a general case in which the DB returns an array of menu items.

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses 2 loops to create a 4 column table from an assoc array. `$z` is calculated to sort rows in each column in ascending order.

```
$count = count($result);
$rows= floor($count/5);
for ($x = 0; $x <= $rows; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y <= 4; $y++) {
        $z=($rows*$y)+$x+$y;
        if($z<$count){
            $html .="<td>".$result[$z]['fmprmlink']."</td>\n";
        }else{
            $html .="<td></td>\n";
        }
        }
    $html .="</tr>\n";
}
$html .="</table>";
echo  $html;
```

[image]

Comment: Edit your image . Half of the answer was white and empty.